# Volumes in testcontainers-go

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, openldap, testcontainers

I have a docker-compose file which I am trying to recreate using [testcontainers-go](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go?tab=doc):

```
version: '3'
services:
  node1:
    image: "osixia/openldap:1.3.0"
    command: ['--copy-service', '--loglevel=debug']
    environment:
      - LDAP_ORGANISATION=Test
      - LDAP_DOMAIN=test.com
      - LDAP_BASE_DN=dc=test,dc=com
      - LDAP_TLS=false
    ports:
      - "3898:389"
    volumes:
      - "/path/to/testdata/node1.ldif:/container/service/slapd/assets/config/bootstrap/ldif/custom/node1.ldif"
```

Below is the go code:

```
ldapPort, err := nat.NewPort("tcp", "389")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

ctx := context.Background()
req := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
    Image:        imageName,
    ExposedPorts: []string{ldapPort.Port() + "/" + ldapPort.Proto()},
    Env: map[string]string{
        "LDAP_ORGANISATION": "Test",
        "LDAP_DOMAIN": "test.com",
        "LDAP_BASE_DN": "dc=test,dc=com",
        "LDAP_TLS": "false",
    },

    BindMounts: map[string]string{
        "/path/to/testdata/node1.ldif":
            "/container/service/slapd/assets/config/bootstrap/ldif/custom/node.ldif",
    },
    WaitingFor:   wait.ForLog("slapd starting"),

}

ldapC, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
    ContainerRequest: req,
    Started:          true,
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer ldapC.Terminate(ctx)
```

The docker-compose file works fine, but when I attempt to run the container using go, the container crashes, and its log contains the following:

```
sed: cannot rename /container/service/slapd/assets/config/bootstrap/ldif/custom/sedah0ove: Device or resource busy
```

I am not sure what the difference is between the go code and the docker-compose declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually in the question, in this case:

```
Cmd:          []string{"--copy-service"}
```

needed to be added to the `testcontainers.ContainerRequest`.

From the [osixia/docker-openldap](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap) documentation:

> Since startup script modifies ldif files, you must add --copy-service argument to entrypoint if you don't want to overwrite them.

I added this to my docker-compose file but forgot it in the Go code.